# Authentication infromation is not provided when I use Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I use the Django Rest Framework, but there seems I can not access, need permission to do this:

> Authentication infromation is not provided.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

### How to resolve this issue?

**EDIT -1**

My code in my views.py:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def task_list(request):
    '''
    List all tasks, or create a new task.
    '''
    if request.method == 'GET':
        tasks = Task.objects.all()
        serializer = TaskSerializer(tasks, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = TaskSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


# detail
@api_view(['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def task_detail(request, pk):
    try:
        task = Task.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Task.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = TaskSerializer(task)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        serializer = TaskSerializer(task, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        task.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Comment: what is the authentication backend you are using for your Django project?

Comment: How to set it ?

Comment: check http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#setting-the-authentication-scheme

Comment: @ArpitGoyal Now I have set the Rest Framework authentication background.

Comment: set it to an empty tuple and then try.

Comment: @ArpitGoyal now, there will pop-up a username and password box, what should I fill with?

Comment: It force me to fill the username and password, then what can I do.

Comment: have you provided any authentication scheme in your API view?

Comment: @ArpitGoyal I have edited my post, see it.

Comment: @heofling Your comment is the answer, thank you, you can post your answer bellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just incase you are still developing its better if you set the authentication class to allow allow any.. then change it whenever it is needed...

```
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
   'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
)
```

hope that helps..

Answer (score 0):

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
@authentication_classes([])
def task_list(request):
    '''
    List all tasks, or create a new task.
    '''
    if request.method == 'GET':
        tasks = Task.objects.all()
        serializer = TaskSerializer(tasks, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = TaskSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

add `@authentication_classes([])` to your function decorators

or

add this in `settings.py`

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    ),
}
```

or

just login django admin site with same browse,all will fine!

Because the default `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` is `'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication'` which is Use Django's session framework for authentication.